# Word2vec Skipgram codes

Tags: python, word2vec

I build a program and a part of my program has a function to find the windowData with `window_size = 2`

**My code:**

```
string = [['I', 'have', 'a', 'pen', 'to', 'use']]

window_size = 2
windowData = []
for lines in string:
    for index,word in enumerate(lines):
        for words in lines[max(index-window_size,0):min(index+window_size,len(string)+1)]:
            if words != word:
                windowData.append([word,words])

print(windowData)
```

**current output:**

```
[['I', 'have'], ['have', 'I'], ['a', 'I'], ['a', 'have'], ['pen', 'have']]
```

From my understanding about the skip-gram it should be something like this, right? (Please correct me if I am wrong)

**Expected output:**

```
[['I', 'have'], ['I', 'a'], ['have', 'I'], ['have', 'a'], ['have', 'pen'], ['a', 'have'], ['a', 'I'], ['a', 'pen'],['a', 'to'],  ['pen', 'a'], ['pen', 'have'], ['pen', 'to'], ['pen', 'use'], ['to', 'pen'], ['to', 'a'],['to', 'use'], ['use', 'pen'],['use', 'to']]
```

I understand that learning only programming language alone is not enough but I should focus more on the problem solving. If possible, please suggest me some sites as well. Thank you.

Comment: if you want me to suggest some link, tell me what is your end goal or what you are trying to do

Comment: I would like to learn more about different problem solving related to programming using python. Is there any website or practices to train on different programming tasks on NLP or machine learning related tasks? I tried kaggle too.

Comment: for the machine learning or data science related you should check out scikit learn and pandas library. they have their own sites. scikit has countvectorizer and so much more. or check new library [dask](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/dask/info).

Comment: Thank you I have checked it and in the meantime just would like to find some related sites that could give me more exercise to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few observations:

- It's a bad idea to call a list-of-lists-of-strings by the variable name 'string'; if in fact here it's the kind of list-of-tokenized-texts commonly used in `Word2Vec`, a name like 'sentences' or 'texts' is clearer.
- You don't want to re-enumerate `lines` each nested loop, but rather work on the current-item of the outer loop. So the loop over `sentences` would give a `sentence`. You'd loop over the `sentence` to get each `word`.
- These context-word to target-word pairs are actually a great place to use Python's *tuples*, essentially tiny immutable lists created at the moment of need - just use parentheses rather than square-brackets.
- You don't need to add one to the length of the `sentence` when slicing out the end-truncated window, because the length is already the actual count of elements, which is one higher than the last position. But you do need to add one to `index + window_size`, because the slicing operation (`[x:y]`) is *exclusive* of the second value (*y*).
- If you are in fact intending for this loop to handle many texts, you may not want to return all pairs as one giant list of pairs from all texts. Instead, you might want to return one list-of-pairs per each list-of-words in the input.
- When just starting out and struggling to understand, it helps to use very-descriptive variable names, and break out interim results to separate lines in named variables, for clarity.

Try this minimally-altered version which reflects those changes:

```
sentences = [['I', 'have', 'a', 'pen', 'to', 'use']]

window_size = 2
pairs_for_all_sentences = []

for sentence in sentences:
    this_sentence_pairs = []

    for index, target_word in enumerate(sentence): 
        window_words = sentence[max(index - window_size, 0) : min(index + window_size + 1, len(sentence))]

        for window_word in window_words:
            if window_word != target_word:
                this_sentence_pairs.append((window_word, target_word))

    pairs_for_all_sentences.append(this_sentence_pairs)

 print(pairs_for_all_sentences)
```

A final note: compared to how real skip-gram pairs are created, this isn't exactly right. While no pair is generated for the word to itself, if the same word appears within the window, a word-to-word pair is created. So in the sentence "I am very very happy", two `('very', 'very')` pairs will actually be trained.

Comment: Thank you so much sir. You have been a big help in guiding me to understand word2vec.

Comment: Sir, regarding the final note. May I know for example, if we have such sentence with repeating word and in order to fully utilizing skip-gram, we should make sure that the word for window_word and target_word to be different. From the code above, you have already design it to be window_word!=target_word; so the current code should have already solved the mentioned issue,right? Thank you

Comment: My code has just copied your code, with corrections in function and style. And so it still has the `window_word != target_word` test to try to skip the middle word. But if the *same* word also appeared next-to the middle word, the current test would also skip that neighbor. But, actual skip-gram implementations with which I am familiar wouldn't skip that neighbor. So the code does something useful, that's maybe good enough, but not exactly what real skip-gram iterations do.

Comment: For example, you can view the skip-gram loop in the pure-Python `Word2Vec` implementation in the `gensim` library at: https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/97783a40aa1d00ca7942b8ab483fd65a2075f8b6/gensim/models/word2vec.py#L190 – note that it works off the index-positions in both the outer and inner loops. So it can skip the center word by checking if the positions are the same, rather than that the words are equal, and if the same word appears in a different position, it will still be trained.

Comment: Now I understand it. Thank you so much sir. I will try other implementations, too. If possible, could you suggest me some new topics related to NLP or word2vec？Recently, I studied on Fasttext, Doc2vec, DependencyBasedWordEmbedding and would like to learn more. Thank you again

Answer (score 1):

**use itertools:**

```
from itertools import combinations

string = ['I', 'have', 'a', 'pen', 'to', 'use']
window_size = 2
print(list(combinations(string, window_size)))
```

**output:**

```
[('I', 'have'), ('I', 'a'), ('I', 'pen'), ('I', 'to'), ('I', 'use'), ('have', 'a'), ('have', 'pen'), ('have', 'to'), ('have', 'use'), ('a', 'pen'), ('a', 'to'), ('a', 'use'), ('pen', 'to'), ('pen', 'use'), ('to', 'use')]
```

Comment: this is not working. If I use window_size = 3 then it will get [('I', 'have', 'a'), ('I', 'have', 'pen'), ('I', 'have', 'to'), ('I', 'have', 'use'), ('I', 'a', 'pen'), ('I', 'a', 'to'), ('I', 'a', 'use'), ('I', 'pen', 'to'), ('I', 'pen', 'use'), ('I', 'to', 'use'), ('have', 'a', 'pen'), ('have', 'a', 'to'), ('have', 'a', 'use'), ('have', 'pen', 'to'), ('have', 'pen', 'use'), ('have', 'to', 'use'), ('a', 'pen', 'to'), ('a', 'pen', 'use'), ('a', 'to', 'use'), ('pen', 'to', 'use')].... this is too much different from expected output of skip-gram

Comment: what shoud be the output at window size = 3 ?

Comment: Do you want permutations rather than combinations @Nihal? Your question lists permutations...